# iFrame OnLoad event in IE not firing after Tapestry Zone update

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, onload

I have a Tapestry zone, inside which is an `<iframe>` element. I wanted to do run a simple JS function (just hiding and enabling some stuff, nothing fancy) when the iframe is done loading.

In chrome and firefox, it works just fine, but I'm having issues with IE 9.

```
function afterExportLoad() {
    // hide throbber gif
    // enable submit button
}
```

So, natually, I tried binding it to iframe like this (inline)

```
<iframe onload="afterExportLoad()" .../>
```

via PrototypeJS

```
exportFrame.observe('load', afterExportLoad);
```

via native JS

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    exportFrame.addEventListener("load", afterExportLoad, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    exportFrame.attachEvent("onload", afterExportLoad);
} else {
    exportFrame.onload = afterExportLoad;
}
```

Using any way above, it works in everything but IE, but in IE, after the iframe is loaded, the gif is "frozen" and the button is still disabled.

Is there a way to make it work in IE9 (and possibly any other IE versions)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was fiddling around a bit and got to this solution:

Added browser checks in the function

```
function afterExportLoad() {
    if (document.getElementsByName('downloadFrame').length > 0) {
        var exportFrame = document.getElementsByName('downloadFrame')[0];

        if ((Prototype.Browser.IE && exportFrame.readyState == "complete") || (!Prototype.Browser.IE)) {
            // my stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Changed the event

```
<iframe onreadystatechange="afterExportLoad();" ...>
```

And in another function that listenes on zone update where iframe is

```
if (document.getElementsByName('downloadFrame').length > 0) {
        var exportFrame = document.getElementsByName('downloadFrame')[0];
        if (!Prototype.Browser.IE) {
            exportFrame.stopObserving('readystatechange', exportLoad);
            exportFrame.onload = exportLoad;
        }
    }
```

If any1 comes up with a better solution, let me know :)